# gtksourceview language file regex - look behind

Tags: xml, regex, gedit, gtksourceview

I'm trying to extend the C language definition found in gtksourceview-3.0, the full original file can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=DVzEgmy3). I just want to make a few syntax rules uses regex's, so I can syntax highlight stuff like functions, class members in gedit. Functions are easy enough, I just added my own context for them with a regex:

```
<context id="myfunc" style-ref="myfunc">
    <match>\w+(?=\()</match>
</context>
```

ie. then I can colour anything like `function()` by applying a style rule to `myfunc`. I'm finding it harder to do member variables, e.g. I want to colour the `bar` in `foo.bar`. Normally I'd use a look-behind regex like

```
<match>(?<=\.)\w+</match>
```

but it doesn't seem to work (and it breaks the other syntax highlighting rules!). At this point I'm stuck because I don't know which regex flavour is being used here, apparently it doesn't support look-behinds, and I don't know much about XML. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone from the gedit mailing list answered me, apparently XML does not like the `<` character, it needs to be replaced:

```
(?&lt;=...)
```

It works then. The regex flavour is PCRE.